# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox wait until images are loaded

Tags: perl

Using this Perl module, how would I wait for the page to load all the images? (I am trying to screenshot image which is part of the age)

I tried `$agent->success` and this only checks if the page is loaded (doesn't check the images).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a wait method in the module but you can check if the element is visible yet and loop through and wait for it to be visible.

```
FOO: {while(1){
   if($gent->is_visible($element)){
        print "Image Downloaded\n";   
        last FOO;         
    }
    else{
       print "Downloading image...\n"; #This might print until image is downloaded
       sleep(10);
    }
}}
```